# Populate specific html elements with javascript variable values

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a JS-function that counts duplicate keys from array of objects and prints keys (category names) and the amount of duplicate keys.

What I want to do is loop through a set of html-elements with specific class and print the values in them.

Here is the HTML I want to achieve

```
<table>
   <th>Category name</th>
   <th>Category count</th>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Shoes</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Shirts</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Hats</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">3</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And here is what I have achieved so far with my javascript function.

```
   <table>
   <th>Category name</th>
   <th>Category count</th>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Shoes</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Shoes</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name">Shoes</td>
         <td class="cat_amount">2</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

So basically i probably should somehow loop through all the elements and all the values and individually inject the values but i don't know how.

My code:

```js
var myObject = [
  {
    "product": "Tennis shoes",
    "price": "10€",
    "categoryname": "Shoes"
  },
  {
    "product": "High heels",
    "price": "40€",
    "categoryname": "Shoes"
  },
  {
    "product": "Basic shirt",
    "price": "20€",
    "categoryname": "Shirts"
  },
  {
    "product": "Huge Cap",
    "price": "15€",
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  },
  {
    "product": "Mage hat",
    "price": "25€",
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  },
  {
    "product": "Wizard hat",
    "price": "45€",
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  }
];
function countCategorynames() {
   var counter = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i += 1) {
counter[this.myObject[i].categoryname] = (counter[this.myObject[i].categoryname] || 0) + 1;
   }
   for (var key in counter) {
      if (counter[key] > 0) {
         console.log("we have ", key, " duplicated ", counter[key], " times");

         var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_name');
         for (var i = 0; i < el1.length; i++) {
            el1[i].innerHTML = key;
         }//for
         var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_amount');
         for (var i = 0; i < el2.length; i++) {
            el2[i].innerHTML = counter[key];
         }//for
      }//if
   }// for
}// function
```

```html
<table>
   <th>Category name</th>
   <th>Category count</th>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name"></td>
         <td class="cat_amount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name"></td>
         <td class="cat_amount"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="cat_name"></td>
         <td class="cat_amount"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="countCategorynames()">Count</button>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Also, provide the keys and values for `myObject`.

Comment: Added the snippet and objects keys and values

Comment: Very good. Now it is a [mcve] +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Here's an example of one way to loop through your values and insert them into a table.

```js
// declaration of myObject for this example
var myObject = [{
    "categoryname": "Shoes"
  },
  {
    "categoryname": "Shoes"
  },
  {
    "categoryname": "Shirts"
  },
  {
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  },
  {
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  },
  {
    "categoryname": "Hats"
  }
];

var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_name');
var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_amount');

function countCategorynames() {
  var counter = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    counter[myObject[i].categoryname] = (counter[myObject[i].categoryname] || 0) + 1;
  }

  var j = 0; // variable to use as a counter for the table

  for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > 0) {
      console.log("we have ", key, " duplicated ", counter[key], " times");
      //This prints out each categoryname and the amount of duplicates
      //for example 
      //we have Shoes duplicated 2 times
      //we have Shirts duplicated 1 times etc...
      el1[j].innerHTML = key;
      el2[j++].innerHTML = counter[key]; // increment the counter
    }
  }
}

countCategorynames();
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Category name</th>
  <th>Category count</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat_name"></td>
    <td class="cat_amount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat_name"></td>
    <td class="cat_amount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat_name"></td>
    <td class="cat_amount"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From the looks of what you have in your code so far, `myObject` seems to be an array of objects; you may want to consider renaming it. If it isn't an array, then you'll need to loop through it using the keys rather than just the `.length` property.

You were declaring `el1` and `el2` multiple times, which isn't really *wrong* but doesn't need to be done. You can declare the variables one time and refer to them in each iteration, since the elements inside the node list aren't changing.

The way you had it set up, you were grabbing the last value for both the category name and the number each time, so that's the only value that was getting applied. Your code was heading in the right direction; it was just the timing that was off.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i wanted to achieve and thanks for the detailed info also!

Comment: Happy to help. JavaScript is full of nuances that can easily be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

both for loops you are running to embed the html is at wrong place.. those will always run and finally updated the last value to your html.

You need to do some changes in code as follows:

```js
function countCategorynames(myObject) {
  var counter = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i += 1) {
    counter[myObject[i].categoryname] = (counter[myObject[i].categoryname] || 0) + 1;
  }
        var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_name');
      var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat_amount');
  for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > 0) {
      console.log("we have ", key, " duplicated ", counter[key], " times");
      //This prints out each categoryname and the amount of duplicates
      //for example 
      //we have Shoes duplicated 2 times
      //we have Shirts duplicated 1 times etc...


      //This is my attempt to get all elements with class 
      //'cat_name' and 'cat_amount'
      //and populate them with values from the object
     el1[i].innerHTML = key;
     el2[i].innerHTML = counter[key];

    }
  }
}
```